# Does Visual Studio Code provide a procedure/snippet to create a new Java class file similar to Eclipse?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm playing with VS Code and I'm wondering if there is a way to quickly create a new class file in a project similar to others popular IDEs. At the moment I'm stuck to manually creating the new file, naming it `something.java`, and fill it with the necessary code. I've already installed the common Java extensions pack (debugger, dep.viewer, language support, maven).

Any clue? Maybe a third party extension?

Answer (score 5):

The only shortcut I know so far is to use the code templates.
Create the new file, name it accordingly ("example.java") and enter "class" or "interface" in the new file. Then hit + and select the correct suggestion:
[image]

VSC then creates a skeleton for the class/interface based on the filename.

Comment: _name it accordingly ("example.class")_ -> You mean "example.java" I presume.